# Segment Monotonous Region with no Edges (Linear Gradient) in an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I'm in need of extracting the "largest" region in an image where intensities are monotonously varying such that we do not detect any (or very few) edges. In other words the gradients are linear and second derivatives are more or less constant.

For example, in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyIsv.png), when we apply Sobel filter to get [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGngL.png), I am interested in the large center black region. I have tried various techniques, for instance Active Contour Model and Chan Vese Segmentation, with the latter providing promising results, as shown in [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t73eP.png).

Below is my code to reproduce the images:

```
from skimage import filters
edge_sobel = filters.sobel(img)

from skimage.segmentation import chan_vese
cv = chan_vese(edge_sobel, mu=0.25, lambda1=1, lambda2=1, tol=1e-9, max_iter=90,
               dt=0.5, init_level_set="checkerboard", extended_output=True)

plt.imshow(np.flipud(img.T), cmap="gray")
plt.show()

plt.imshow(np.flipud(edge_sobel.T), cmap="gray")
plt.show()

plt.imshow(np.flipud(cv[0].T), cmap="gray")
plt.show()

plt.imshow(np.flipud(img.T), cmap="gray")
plt.imshow(np.flipud(cv[0].T), alpha=.2, cmap="Reds")
plt.show()
```

[image: Grayscale image]
[image: Sobel Edges]
[image: Chan Vese Segmentation]

However, Chan Vese Segmentation is giving results that are too aggressive and I'm missing large chunk of image on the left in the binary image that should've been included in the Segmentation. See the red segmented region overlaid atop the original image.

I'll also note that I want to do it fast, for real-time application. I would also note that the Active Contour model didn't quite work as I want to expand the initial region rather than contracting it and I also can't know each time where to place that initial region.
[image: Monotonous Region Overlaid atop Orignal]

Can you please help get me a precise segmentation? I want to segment/filter out the entire black region in the image below:
[image: Desired segmentation]

Comment: Why not keep it simple and keep Sobel to make your image binary, then maybe dilate if needed and finally keep the largest of the obtained black regions. There will be no probem for real time with your resolution. I recommand using opencv. If you provide a few raw images I could give it a try

Comment: Thresholding sobel output only yields edges. I need to segment out the entire black region shown in the last image.

Comment: Indeed, edge detection "only" draws boundaries. If gradient is sufficient, your image is splitted into distinct regions by these boundaries, then using connected components to keep or discard them will generate your segmentation mask. Any raw images available?

Comment: @Matt-Mac-Muffin: edge filters always fail to return continuous contours.

Comment: Humans would probably disagree on how to segment this image. What would your segmentation be, and why ?

Comment: with some post-processing on the edge map, I think you can easily segment. But indeed this kind of processing is always "fine tuned" with some threshold parameters, and will not be generic unless dataset is very homogenous. that's why I was asking for a few raw images